# Add custom shortcodes to the Welcome Mail

Tags: shortcode, email

I need to add a custom shortcode to the welcome email of my website.

I'm not expert; what I need is in plugabble.php file?

I tried a lot of plugins for edit email template but nothing seems work.

Is there anyone that can help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Ps. This is the one time link script that I have modified:

```
function one_time_link(){

/* Generate a unique token: */
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(),1));

$file = "/tmp/urls.txt";
if( !($fd = fopen($file,"a")) )
        die("Could not open $file!");

if( !(flock($fd,LOCK_EX)) )
        die("Could not aquire exclusive lock on $file!");

if( !(fwrite($fd,$token."\n")) )
        die("Could not write to $file!");

if( !(flock($fd,LOCK_UN)) )
        die("Could not release lock on $file!");

if( !(fclose($fd)) )
        die("Could not close file pointer for $file!");

/* Report the one-time URL to the user: */
$linkResult = "Your One Time Link\n";

}
```

I've tried this:

```
class LinkGenerator {
public function one_time_link(){

/* Generate a unique token: */
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(),1));

/* This file is used for storing tokens. One token per line. */
$file = "/tmp/urls.txt";
if( !($fd = fopen($file,"a")) )
        die("Could not open $file!");

if( !(flock($fd,LOCK_EX)) )
        die("Could not aquire exclusive lock on $file!");

if( !(fwrite($fd,$token."\n")) )
        die("Could not write to $file!");

if( !(flock($fd,LOCK_UN)) )
        die("Could not release lock on $file!");

if( !(fclose($fd)) )
        die("Could not close file pointer for $file!");

/* Report the one-time URL to the user: */
$linkResult = "Your Special Link\n";

echo "$linkResult";

}
}

add_filter( 'wpbe_tags', 'wpse_225078_wpbd_tags' );

function wpse_225078_wpbd_tags( $tags ) {
    $genLink = 'LinkGenerator';
    $a = new $genLink();
    $tags['one_time_link'] = $a->one_time_link(); 

    return $tags;
}
```

It seems correct for me but it doesn't work...

Comment: Hi Euca 90, welcome to WPSE! We would love to help, but you really need to clarify your question - it's simply too broad to answer. Perhaps specify which plugins you have tried, _why_ exactly you need this custom shortcode (and perhaps what it does), and maybe any relevant code you already have?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I have created a php script that generates a one-time link.  I would add this ever-changing link to each welcome email sent to the new members. I find WP Better Emails that allows me to create custom tags for my template...but I would like to understand how to take the new link generated before sending welcome emails to new users. 

Do you understand what i'm trying to explain?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at [the faq](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-better-emails/faq/), you can register tags with PHP - you would just need to integrate your "php script" within your filter function (which I can't really help with unless you post some code)

Comment: Yes, I have added script above (the variable is: $linkResult = "<a href='http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/wp-content/custom-php/get_file.php?q=$token'>Your One Time Link</a>\n"; )

Comment: Then the script connects to get_file.php that verifies the generated link.

I would like to understand how to take the new link generated ($linkResult - how to call function one_time_link()) before sending welcome emails to new users.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated question and comments, this should be what you are looking for:

```
function wpse_225078_wpbd_tags( $tags ) {
    $tags['one_time_link'] = one_time_link();

    return $tags;
}

add_filter( 'wpbe_tags', 'wpse_225078_wpbd_tags' );
```

The idea is to hook into the tag system provided by WPBE so you can just use `%one_time_link%` in your email template.

Please note that this assumes `one_time_link` is a function in your theme/loaded within the WordPress environment.

There's no guarantee this will work, but I hope it puts you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, but I should not first call the function one_time_link(); (inserted in function.php) and then take the variable $linkResult and insert it in an <a href></a>?

Comment: Yes you are correct - sorry, it's bit confusing without knowing your setup in detail. I hope I've helped enough that you can finally solve it, but let me know if you get really stuck.

Comment: I have added script above - it seems correct for me but it doesn't work